# How to add list of dictionary key data items into QTableWidget using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Here is my code,i want to add my list of items into qtabl widget in one key i have a list of items when i want to add my list of items in to qtable widget i am getting the problem i.e my last items is overriding the previous item because of the idx index in columns.i tried many ways but i not able to all the items in qtable widget.

Given below is my sample tried code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from functools import partial
import os, sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.data_arraylist = {'85207':[{'item1':"Fruites", 'Qty':'10','Price':'100','total':'100'},{'item1':"Banana", 'Qty':'20','Price':'200','total':'200'}],'97895':{'item1':"vegitables", 'Qty':'2kg','Price':'200','total':'200'},'97055':{'item1':"snacks", 'Qty':'10p','Price':'200','total':'200'}}
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dataw = QtGui.QWidget()
        self._gridlayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.vboxdata = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dataw)
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.vboxdata.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.timelabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.orderbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Orders")
        self.newbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("New")
        self.newbtn.clicked.connect(self.items_list)
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.timelabel)
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.orderbtn)
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.newbtn)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox1)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.dataw, 0, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.vbox, 1, 0)
        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)
    def items_list(self):
        self.mainw2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.mainw2)
        self.newvbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mainw2)
        self.linedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.search = QtGui.QLabel("Search")
        self.newhbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.newhbox.addWidget(self.linedit)
        self.newhbox.addWidget(self.search)
        self.newvbox.addLayout(self.newhbox)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table.setRowCount(5)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("S.no, Item Description,Qty,Rate(Rs:),Total").split(','))
        self.newvbox.addWidget(self.table)
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print event,event.key(),QtCore.Qt.Key_Return
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            text_key = self.linedit.text()
            self.searchitems(text_key)
    def searchitems(self,text_key):
        if str(text_key) in  self.data_arraylist:
            for ridx,row in enumerate(range(1)):
                for idx, column in enumerate(range(5)):
                    if idx ==0:
                            self.table.setItem(row,column,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(ridx+1)))
                    elif idx ==1:
                        for i in range(len(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)])):
                            self.table.setItem(row,column,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(
                                    str(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)][i][
                                            'item1'])))

                    elif idx ==2:
                        for i in range(len(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)])):
                            self.table.setItem(row,column,
                                               QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(
                                                   self.data_arraylist[str(
                                                       text_key)][i]['Qty'])))
                    elif idx ==3:
                        for i in range(len(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)])):
                            self.table.setItem(row,column,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)][i]['Price'])))
                    elif idx ==4:
                        for i in range(len(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)])):
                            self.table.setItem(row,column,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)][i]['total'])))
        else:
            pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.setGeometry(500,500,800,400)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. Add a [mcve] that we can run and observe - your parial code is not  executable. Do not post your whole code - simplyfy it as far as possible  so nothing can be left out.

Comment: sir I am beginner in pyqt4 i dont know why you are put my question in hold here i got the problem is when i assign the list of items in qtable widget last item is overriding the previous items in list ,so in my table i got the last item  only here i print the row and column both item is tacking the same row and column position idx,i dont have much knowledge in this pyqt4 so please consider my question and help me out of this problem

Comment: It does not matter whether you are a beginner or not, here we are interested in the question. He has not just put you on hold but we have been members of the community, since your original question indicates that something in your code does not work but the code you provided was not useful to understand where the problem is, so in that state it was impossible to help you because it was off-topic for the site, I recommend you read [ask], go through the [tour] again and review what we refer to with a [mcve]

Comment: sir just now i edit the code i already mention my problem is here in dictionary i have a list of items here  i got the only last item i.e [banana item] in my table i am not able to get the first of  the list[fruites]how can i display the list of items in qtable widget .i know this syntax only to represent the items in table.please sir hel p me

Comment: try looping over your input list and create an entry into your widget for every element in your dictionary: google it - f.e. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3rtpv0/pyqt4_qtablewidget_with_python_dictionary/

Comment: A [mcve] would be: a main widget, a input line and the qtablewidget + your data - the rest is irrelevant to solving your problem.  There is also lots of silly things happening: `for ridx,row in enumerate(range(1)):` - loops exactly once - whatfor? `ridx_row = 1` would have the same effect if you use it instead of ridx and row.
`for idx, column in enumerate(range(5)):` is `(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)` ... what for is this needed ? You probably need a `for cat in self.data_arraylist:` and then distinguish betwen a list of items or a single item `if isinstance(self.data_arraylist[cat],list):`

Comment: and then do stuff ... the whole looping thingy does not make lots of sense (to me). You might want to rewrite it.

Comment: just remove the for loop in each index and use ridx inplace of i then you will get the answer ex:self.table.setItem(row,column,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data_arraylist[str(text_key)][ridx]['item1'])))